# Any tool that can help on manually label a time series data please?

Tags: time-series, preprocessing, finance

i am working with a 10 years weekly financial time series data set, which has the standard format date open high low close volume.

i would like to manually label (classify) the data set with label/class uptrend,downtrend,buy,sell n etc in a new column.

my question is whether there is any tool to help on this data processing work.

For example, maybe the data can be loaded and plotted. i can then select a range (sequence)of data from the graph and give a label to it.

Comment: Most languages that you would do data science with (python, R, etc) should be able to handle this for you with very little effort. From OHLC data, you'll need to create sub-classifications like "O < C = stock rose" or "O > C = stock fell" and then create queries like "4 'stock rose' in a row" is an 'upward trend'". That should be fairly trivial to write on your own.

Comment: thanks for your comment, but i think it would be more difficult than this. For example, a uptrend can surely be stock rose 4 in a row, but it can also rose 1 fall 1 rose twice fall 1 and rose again, i hope i can classify this and feed into a NN to learn the pattern. Thats why i was thinking an "interactive" graph. Imaging labelling a photo or picture, there are a lot of service out on the net, but i have not found one for time series.

Comment: That's fine - you can define whatever parameters / timeframe / etc you want to write to define "uptrend". The point remains that with some querying you should be able to do this on your own. The research time you've spent for a tool might already be more than what these queries would take you to write :)